# How to know the page is rendered or redirected in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rendering

After clicking on the "**Save**" button of the *account* form, the page is rendered to the *edit account* itself because the validation did not pass successfully. I need to know that the form is redirected or rendered after that validation action.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share your controller code please?

Comment: _'I need to know that the form is redirected or rendered after that validation action.'_ where?

Comment: @kiddorails I need to know on the form of the account.

Comment: Questions get better answers if they 1) show code that is tried and 2) where in the code they need help. E.g. in your case: do you need this knowledge in the controller, in a model, in the view? From your comments on the first answer, I seem to understand you are having troubles when rendering the form? Do you use a standard `form_for` or something like `simple_form`? It also helps _why_ you need this. E.g. to show validations or an alert, which have possibly completely different answers/approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Generally update method looks like this.

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
   end
end
```

On save, update method is called. Check this method, If @article updated successfully it will redirect to show page otherwise edit page will get rendered.

Comment: Sorry, but I am already using this functionality, I think I did not provide the sufficient information. I need to check on the form that it is rendered or redirected

Comment: @PiyushChaudhary you can check this by `@article.errors.present?` if it returns true that means validation has not been passed otherwise it is passed.

Answer (score 0):

A few easy solutions:

- when you decide in your controller whether you will re-render or redirect, also set an instance-variable which you can check in the view
- when rendering the form, check if the object you are editing is `valid?` (will return true if it saved succesfully, false otherwise)

It is a bit unclear why you need this info, I hope you are already showing the validation errors? Simple-form will do this automatically (on the fields). If you do it yourself, you could iterate over `@<your-object>.errors.messages`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is whether the update action has been run when you're on the edit page.  The conventional way to do this is to check errors on the @article object:

```
<%- if @article.errors.blank? %>
  No errors so hasn't been run through update action
<% else %>
  Has been run through update and has some errors
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, you could add an instance variable in your controller, then check for that on your page:

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @run_update = true
  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
   end
end
```

View:

```
<%- if @run_update %>
  Has been rendered
<% end %>
```

This is because instance variable don't persist after a redirect